# Trigger history - How can I define the last updated column?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, audit

I am trying to implement a history trigger function in PostgreSQL. I've written this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION history_update() 
RETURNS trigger AS

$$

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO data_history(id, geom, origine, descrizione, img, created, created_by)
    VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.geom, NEW.origine, NEW.descrizione, NEW.img, current_timestamp, current_user);

    RETURN NEW;

END;

$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON data 
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE history_update();
```

Now I would like to add another column (called `last_update`) where to set the name of the column in which the value was updated.

For example if the updated value is in the column called "supporto", in the column `last_updated` I want to see the name of the same column with the updated value (called "supporto").

What if the updated values in the column are more than one? Possible suggestion:

1. Insert in the row of the column "last_updated" more values
2. Insert as many column as  the number of the column in the original table (for example `last_updated1`, `last_updated2`...)

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: You need to go through all columns and find ones that changed. Then you store comma-separated values in `last_update`.

Comment: It's possible, but i would use this trigger for tables that have many field that will be changed, then the column last_update willl be (1,2,3,dx,sx,2,3). Not very intellegible.